# Java: String Parsing for layers of brackets

Tags: java, brackets, string-parsing

I'm very new to stack overflow, and I've been learning Java for a few months now. I have so far created a calculator which can find multiple sets of brackets and correctly work them out. However I'm struggling to figure out how to get it to correctly find brackets inside of brackets correctly.

For example;

Say I input the below string...

"10+(2+(3*2))"

I basically want it to set "3*2" to another string. How would I go about getting whats inside the deepest brackets?

Thanks in advance for any help/advice, ask questions if I've been unclear or too vague.

Here is what I have so far for checking for brackets;

```
public static String checkForBrackets(String formula) {

        for (int i = 0; i < formulaChars.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < formulaChars.size(); j++) {
                if ((formulaChars.get(i) == ')') && (formulaChars.get(j) == '(')) {
                    bracketFormula = formula.substring(j + 1, i);
                    formulaChars.clear();
                }
            }
        }
     System.out.println(bracketFormula)
    }
```

The for loops are checking for the left most opening and closing bracket.

If I was to input the string "10+(2+(3*2))", the code would return "2+(3*2" instead of what I want; "3*2"

Comment: Please can you share your code of what you have done so far?

Comment: You can use Stack data structure for this. You can keep invoking push() for every open parenthesis and pop when you encounter a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Do you really mean deepest brackets?  You would have to parse the entire input before determining the deepest.

Comment: Do you know parse trees? You can use the to solve these kind of issues:. http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Trees/ParseTree.html

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I strongly suggest you use a parser for this problem. That way you can get the correct priority for expressions like 1 + 2 * 3. If you want to write one yourself then I'd recommend the "Recursive Decent" parser pattern.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help and suggestions